# For which value of a , b , d these 2 functions are equal

Tags: calculus, functions

Functions :
$$ f(x) = (ax+b)/(x+d) $$
And the inverse one :
$$ g(x) = (xd-b)/(a-x) $$
I tried to solve it and I got this :
$$ a(-x^2 + ax + b) = d(x^2 + xd -b) $$
But I can't go further, How can I solve this?

Comment: of course we shoud have it right for every x - { x=-d , x=a }

Comment: g(x) = f^(-1)(x)

Answer (score 3):

Necessary condition: the limit at $\infty$ has to be the same. Since
 $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = a$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = -d$, you need $a=-d$.

Can you see why this is also sufficient (e.g., by writing the resulting expressions for $f,g$?)